# How to delete one shape off of powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a macro that deletes all of the tables in my powerpoint and then a different macro to import the new tables from excel. I'm having trouble figuring out how to only delete that shape, however. The code I have right now deletes the title of the slide and all of the comments too (see below for current). Any ideas how to only remove that one shape? OR is it possible to delete only pictures and not text??

```
    Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide, sl_cnt As Long, pr As Object, pr_name As String, ppt As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pr = ppt.Presentations(1)
    For j = 10 To 1 Step -1
        Set sl = pr.Slides(j)
        For i = sl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            sl.Shapes(i).Delete
        Next i
    Next j
    
       'Record the date & time of procedure execution
    Range("DeletePreviousPPTData").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy") & " - " & Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm AM/PM")
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [`Shape.HasTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.hastable) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is deleting all of the shapes on the slide.

Before deleting each shape, make sure that it's a table.

As @BigBen mentioned, .HasTable will identify shapes that are tables, but it'll miss tables contained in content placeholders.

This IsTable function will test for both. Use it like so:

```
Sub YourSubName()

Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide, sl_cnt As Long, pr As Object, pr_name As String, ppt As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pr = ppt.Presentations(1)
    For j = 10 To 1 Step -1
        Set sl = pr.Slides(j)
        For i = sl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1

' ADD THIS TEST
If IsTable(sl.Shapes(i)) then
   sl.Shapes(i).Delete
End if

        Next i
    Next j
    
       'Record the date & time of procedure execution
    Range("DeletePreviousPPTData").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yy") & " - " & Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm AM/PM")
    
End Sub

Function IsTable(oSh As Shape) As Boolean
    
    If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoTable Then
            IsTable = True
        End If
    Else
        If oSh.HasTable Then
            IsTable = True
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: hmm I keep getting a compile error saying its expecting an end sub after the first end if....

Comment: My example isn't a complete subroutine, just a snippet that demonstrates how to call the function from your existing code, then the function itself. In place of the "sl.Shapes(i).Delete" in your code, include the three lines at the top of my example.

Comment: I added it and it says sub or function not defined, what would IsTable be defined as?

Comment: IsTable is a Function ... it's in my answer. You need to add it to your code.

Comment: I'm confused how I'm supposed to put the function inside of the sub. When I try to put the function in it tells me I need to close the sub first

Comment: You don't include functions within subs. You should paste the function below or above the sub (doesn't matter which).

Comment: Check my answer again; I've merged your code and my additions.

Comment: I just realized the reason it may not be working still is that the "table" is not actually a table in excel I just input the data and set it up to look like a table. so I think in this case I need to figure out a way to only delete/replace that one shape